# Table Gets Cut Off When Knitting to PDF

Tags: r

I am in the process of creating a table 1 for my work, but when I knit my R Markdown file to PDF, some of the table gets cut off. Can I modify my code to either knit it landscape or not have half the table cut off?

```
  table_1 <- CreateTableOne(
  vars = vars,
  data = Cambodia,
  factorVars = fvars,
  test = FALSE,
)


tab1 <- kable(
  print(table_1,
        showAllLevels = TRUE,
        printToggle = FALSE,
        noSpaces = TRUE,
        catDigits = 1,
        contDigits = 1),
  caption = paste(
    "Baseline Characteristics of xyz."
  )
)
print(tab1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `kable_styling` from the `kableExtra` package. The option would be `latex_options="scale_down"`. You can use font sizes as well, please see https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf